# Oracle issue with a left outer join subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, left-join, ora-01427

I have a sql which is failing in a left outer join subquery with

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

Here is the `left outer join` query fragment:

```
 LEFT OUTER JOIN (aa.location) LOCATION
    ON (location_info_300.client_num = location.client_num
    AND location_info_300.source = location.source
    AND location_info_300.location_code = location.location_code
    AND 1 =
           (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()
                   OVER(PARTITION BY location_code, client_num, SOURCE
                        ORDER BY expiry_date DESC)
                      AS rec_order_by_expiry_desc
              FROM aa.location l2
             WHERE location.client_num = l2.client_num
               AND location.source = l2.source
               AND location.location_code = l2.location_code
               AND l2.expiry_date >=
                      TO_DATE('01-JAN-' || location_info_300.reporting_year,
                              'DD-MON-YYYY')
               AND l2.effective_date <=
                      TO_DATE('31-DEC-' || location_info_300.reporting_year,
                              'DD-MON-YYYY')))
```

I tried fixing it by doing the following change in the last `AND` criteria:

```
1 = 
(SELECT rec_order_by_expiry_desc
  FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LOCATION_CODE, CLIENT_NUM, SOURCE ORDER BY EXPIRY_DATE DESC) AS REC_ORDER_BY_EXPIRY_DESC
   FROM aa.LOCATION l2
  WHERE location.CLIENT_NUM = l2.CLIENT_NUM
    AND location.SOURCE = l2.SOURCE
    AND location.LOCATION_CODE = l2.LOCATION_CODE
    AND l2.EXPIRY_DATE >= TO_DATE('01-JAN-'||location_info_300.REPORTING_YEAR,'DD-MON-YYYY')
    AND l2.EFFECTIVE_DATE <= TO_DATE('31-DEC-'||location_info_300.REPORTING_YEAR,'DD-MON-YYYY'))
WHERE rec_order_by_expiry_desc = 1)
```

But now I am getting the following error:

```
ORA-00904: "LOCATION_INFO_300"."REPORTING_YEAR": invalid identifier
```

I am not sure what else to try. I hope someone does though!

Comment: "LOCATION_INFO_300" is in where clause from not in from clause.

Comment: checking for 1= (get row number for max expiry date) just checks that there IS a max expiry date for those criteria, and if so then all rows would be returned for that combination of client, source, and location. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're basically checking if the row exists in the subquery? If so, then just do an `EXISTS`:

```
   LEFT OUTER JOIN (aa.location) LOC
                                 ON (location_info_300.client_num = loc.client_num
                                     AND location_info_300.source = loc.source
                                     AND location_info_300.location_code = loc.location_code
                                     AND exists (SELECT null
                                                 FROM   aa.location l2
                                                 WHERE  loc.client_num = l2.client_num
                                                 AND    loc.source = l2.source
                                                 AND    loc.location_code = l2.location_code
                                                 AND    l2.expiry_date >= TO_DATE('01-JAN-' || location_info_300.reporting_year, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
                                                 AND    l2.effective_date <= TO_DATE('31-DEC-' || location_info_300.reporting_year, 'DD-MON-YYYY')))
```

N.B. I changed the alias of the aa.location table, just to avoid any possible conflicts between the outer and sub-query's aa.location tables (much better to make sure that aliases aren't the same as existing identifier names to avoid any potential scope clash issues. Also, it makes it easier to understand when you read the query).

Comment: Which will be better, using `EXISTS` or replacing the `=` with an `IN` so as to check if the record exists, thus avoiding the `ORA-01427` error?

Comment: exists will work faster as it short-circuits to success as soon as it finds any match, rather than getting all matches and then scanning those results

Answer (score 1):

Your first subquery should return exactly one row, but it returns more than one.

This is because you perform an analytic function, which is essentially supposed to return a varied amount of rows. The only way to assert that only one row will be returned is using an aggregate function or using conditions that will assure that.

Regarding the second query, note that you're calling a field from a table that doesn't exist in the given context.

If you're trying to check if a row exists or not, you should read into EXISTS function, or perhaps using COUNT in the subquery.

Edit: here is an example for the second option (the fist was already posted):

```
(SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM aa.location l2
             WHERE location.client_num = l2.client_num
               AND location.source = l2.source
               AND location.location_code = l2.location_code
               AND l2.expiry_date >= TO_DATE('01-JAN-' || location_info_300.reporting_year, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
               AND l2.effective_date <= TO_DATE('31-DEC-' || location_info_300.reporting_year, 'DD-MON-YYYY'))
```

Note that I removed the fields in the PARTITION BY clause and didn't add them in GROUP BY because they conflict with your need of only one row.

Answer (score 1):

checking for 1= (get row number for max expiry date) just checks that there IS a max expiry date for those criteria, and if so then all rows would be returned for that combination of client, source, and location. Is this what you want?

If you want the actual record with the max expiry date, then

```
 LEFT OUTER JOIN (aa.location) LOCATION
    ON (location_info_300.client_num = location.client_num
    AND location_info_300.source = location.source
    AND location_info_300.location_code = location.location_code
    AND location.expiry_date =
           (SELECT MAX(expiry_date)
              FROM aa.location l2
             WHERE location.client_num = l2.client_num
               AND location.source = l2.source
               AND location.location_code = l2.location_code
               AND l2.expiry_date >=
                      TO_DATE('01-JAN-' || location_info_300.reporting_year,
                              'DD-MON-YYYY')
               AND l2.effective_date <=
                      TO_DATE('31-DEC-' || location_info_300.reporting_year,
                              'DD-MON-YYYY')))
```

Comment: What is the difference between your second query and using the example user @boneist gave?

Comment: looking at his, they are essentially identical so I will remove the second query from mine. Thanks for pointing that out.